Has anyone measured the energy output of matter/antimatter annihilation?
I've looked everywhere I can think, this side of paywalls, and everyone provides Feynman diagrams or $E=mc^2$ to describe or calculate annihilation. It occurred to me that virtual particles come into existence and annihilate each other all the time.
I'm trying to understand this disconnect. Does virtual particle creation cause "anti-energy" that counters the energy released during annihilation?
Has anyone actually measured the energy output of a proton/antiproton collision? I couldn't find a record of any such experiment. It's all theoretical calculations. All of my search results are cluttered by "gravity works on antimatter!" announcements.

I'm far from an expert on this topic but I'm not sure how literally the creation/annihilation of matter/antimatter particles as quantum fluctuations are commonly described should be taken.

Virtual particles are a mathematical fiction; they aren't real particles. From https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/185139/123208 "virtual particles exist only in the mathematics of the model used to describe the measurements of real particles". Also see https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/147096/123208 & https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/275099/123208 & links therein.

Proton / antiproton collision is a messy process, with a variety of possible outcomes, and the complexity increases as the collision energy increases. I have some info on that (and a few other annihilation reactions) here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/451337/123208

Since the purpose of LEP was to collide electrons and positrons, I would assume that they made trillions of measurements of what the annihilation of these particles produced.

@PM2Ring, the Casimir effect seems to disagree with you, as does Hawking radiation. Being a mathematic construct doesn't prevent them from being real.

@RobertRapplean Virtual particles are a convenient calculation tool. But they don't have much to do with the Casimir effect. https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/349743/123208 They can be used to explain Hawking radiation, but that's just a heuristic picture, and Hawking himself advised against taking it too seriously. https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/761625/123208

@PM2Ring, virtual particles are containers that hold state, often transferring it from one particle to the next. The state isn't imaginary just because it isn't isn't in a conveniently shaped package. Mathematically, you can think of them as placeholders or a mathematical convenience if you want. We don't know the shape of a quark or a gluon. We aren't even completely sure of the shape of a photon. They're also containers. You're limiting yourself by insisting that one exists and another doesn't.

I'm not sure if this answers your question, but Positron Emission Tomography (PET) is a standard type of medical imaging and uses a matter-antimatter annihilation process - namely electrons and positrons annihilate producing gamma rays.  Some details below: (Referencing Wikipedia)
"The most significant fraction of electron–positron annihilations results in two 511 keV gamma photons being emitted at almost 180 degrees to each other."
(Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positron_emission_tomography)
